# OpenGL поворот с помощью кватерниона

Tags: java, математика, opengl, матрицы, 3d

Создаю 3D камеру, и хочу чтоб была возможность свободно вращать её во всех 3 осях. Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в кватернионах, но понял, что их надо перемножать и вращать матрицу итоговым кватернионом. Получилось примерно так:

```
protected Quaternionf orient;
Quaternionf pitch, yaw, roll;
protected Matrix4f projection;
protected Matrix4f camera;

public void rotateX(float angleX) {
    this.angleX += angleX;
    float rad = org.joml.Math.toRadians(angleX);
        
    pitch.identity();
    pitch.setAngleAxis(rad, 1, 0, 0);
    orient.premul(pitch);
    update();
}
public void rotateY(float angleY) {
    this.angleY += angleY;
    float rad = org.joml.Math.toRadians(angleY);
        
    yaw.identity();
    yaw.setAngleAxis(rad, 0, 1, 0);
    orient.premul(yaw);
    update();
}
public void rotateZ(float angleZ) {
    this.angleZ += angleZ;
    float rad = org.joml.Math.toRadians(angleZ);
        
    roll.identity();
    roll.setAngleAxis(rad, 0, 0, 1);
    orient.premul(roll);
    update();
}
@Override
public void update() {
    camera.identity();
        
    camera.translate(new Vector3f(posX, posY, posZ));
    camera.rotateLocal(orient);
    camera.scale(scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ);

    projection.mul(camera, projView);
        
    EventBus.getInstance().cameraUpdate(this);
}
```

И проблемы складывания рамок (gimbal lock) вроде не происходит, как не поворачиваюсь, вращение по всем осям происходит без проблем. Но появляется другая сложность. Начинает происходить вращение по оси Z тогда когда это не нужно. Например если поднять камеру вверх, затем влево, а потом опустить обратно вниз, то объекты на которые я смотрел изначально будут уже повёрнуты по Z. И даже если просто начать с небольшим радиусом крутить мышью по кругу, то всё начинает вращаться по оси Z.

Comment: Надо сохранять кватернион, а не три угла.